# Como hacer que las imagenes dentro de un card sea de una misma medida sin que se desborde por su tamaño

Tags: html, css

Con que propiedades puedo establecer que una imagen que tengo dentro de un card sea siempre de un mismo tamaño y no el de su tamaño original ya que se desborda y se desalinea todo el texto y la forma

asi se ve actualmente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quisiera que se vea todos de un mismo tamaño

```
 <div class="card  shadow-lg mb-3 bg-white rounded" >
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                
                    <img class="img-fluid "  src="images/<?php echo $producto->imagenPortada?>">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <!-- <div class="card-body"> -->
                        <h5 class="card-title font-weight-bold"><?php echo $producto->nombreArea ?></h5>
                        <p class="card-text"><?php echo $producto->descripcionArea ?></p>
                        
                    <!-- </div> -->
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Lo estoy trabajando con boostrap 4

Comment: La fácil siempre será darle una dimensiones. Eso asume que todas las imágenes se pueden escalar igual; si tienen formas diferentes, se verán raras. Podrías hacer algo que redimensione cada imagen y valide hasta que quede por debajo de las dimensiones máximas...

Comment: @Alfabravo a que te refieres con redimensionar? crear una funcion o algo? o con una propiedad de css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa `class="img-fluid"` en el img para que lo ajuste. Veo que funciona [desde Bootstrap4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/#responsive-images).

Si no, prueba añadiendo un estilo

```
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

y aprovechando que está dentro del col-md y eso, debería ajustarlo al tamaño que corresponde.

Comment: Tiene image fluid pero no lo realiza intentaré añadiendo ese fragmento que me dejaste

Comment: Ok si me sirvio... pero tengo otra duda, como puedo alternar para que un card tenga la imagen del lado izquierdo y el texto del derecho y el card de abajo tenga ahora al reves, la imagen del lado derecho y el texto del izquierdo... mas o menos como alternandolos